# Does Chrome support the lineNumber property on error objects?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, line-numbers

MDN claims that Chrome supports the non-standard property [`Error.prototype.lineNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/lineNumber#Browser_compatibility) *"On error object in handled errors."*. I fiddled around but wasn't able to verify this.

```js
try
{
  throw new Error;
}
catch (error)
{
  alert('lineNumber is ' + error.lineNumber);
}
```

When running the snippet above, only Firefox sets `error.lineNumber` to a numeric value. Safari uses a similar non-standard property `error.line`, while Chrome doesn't seem to have any similar functionality at all. I know the line number is in the [`stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack) if you parse it, and there are libraries to extract it, but the unclarity bothers me.

Is the MDN documentation outdated or am I missing something here?

Comment: Possibly do a console.log on the error object it self to see what properties are available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything here. If V8 (Chrome's JavaScript engine) supported it at some stage, it certainly doesn't seem to currently, so I guess that falls under MDN's "...the behavior may change in the future." Alternately, remember that MDN is collaboratively-edited, it could just always have been wrong about Chrome supporting it.

As the MDN page says, `lineNumber` or something similar is [not in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-error-objects).

Given that neither of us sees any indication that V8 supports it, I've corrected the MDN article.